# c++ program not printing 2d vector grid properly but is close

Tags: c++, vector, output

Im currently trying to parse a text file of numbers into a 2d vector that will be modified later, but with my code so far. I'm getting this:

```
845630179
032918654
190745328
683074912
457201836
219863540
361429705
074186093
074186093�845630179
```

Its fine and all, except it repeats line number 9 and puts junk at the end.

If i put an enter at the end of the text, it prints out this:

```
845630179
032918654
190745328
683074912
457201836
219863540
361429705
074186093
9203574619
```

(the 10th element in the 9th row shouldn't be there)

for reference, here is what the text file looks like:

```
845630179
032918654
190745328
683074912
457201836
219863540
361429705
074186093
920357461
```

This is my code so far:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
//parsing the textfile.
vector<vector<char>> grid;
fstream fin; char ch;
string name (argv[1]); //File Name.
// 2D Vector.
vector<char> temp;
// Temporary vector to be pushed 
// into vec, since its a vector of vectors.
fin.open(name.c_str(),ios::in);
// Assume name as an arbitary file.
while(fin)
{
    ch = fin.get();
    if(ch!='\n') {
        temp.push_back(ch);
        cout << ch;
    }
    else 
    { 
        grid.push_back(temp); 
        temp.clear(); 
        cout << ch;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < grid.size();i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].size();j++) {
        cout << grid[i][j];
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `while(fin)` only guarantees the stream is good when you enter the loop. Bad smurf could happen at `ch = fin.get();`, forr example trying to read past the end of the file, and it passes unchecked. Don't check before reads. Check after the read and before you use the values read.

Comment: Unrelated, why not a `vector` of `string`? You could save a lot of work by `getline`ing into the `string`.

Comment: I tried that and it just puts me in an endless loop @user4581301

Comment: Are you working on Windows? I think it is a Windows problem with CR LF instead of LF. I can't reproduce it on Linux.

Comment: File was opened in text mode. \r\n will have been automatically converted to \n, so that won't be a problem.

Comment: im running a linux VM (cygdrive) @ThomasSablik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One quick fix gets rid of most of your problem:

```
int main()
{
//parsing the textfile.
    vector<vector<char>> grid;
    fstream fin;
    char ch;

    // Hardcoded value. Typing the same thing in over and over while debugging is for suckers.
    string name("data.txt"); //File Name. 
// 2D Vector.
    vector<char> temp;
// Temporary vector to be pushed
// into vec, since its a vector of vectors.
    fin.open(name.c_str(), ios::in);
// Assume name as an arbitary file.
    while (fin.get(ch)) // the change: Slightly different get and getting in the loop
                        // condition. If nothing is gotten the loop doesn't enter
                        // solves almost all of the problems.
    {
        if (ch != '\n')
        {
            temp.push_back(ch);
            cout << ch;
        }
        else
        {
            grid.push_back(temp);
            temp.clear();
            cout << ch; 
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].size(); j++)
        {
            cout << grid[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

output

```
845630179
032918654
190745328
683074912
457201836
219863540
361429705
074186093
920357461845630179032918654190745328683074912457201836219863540361429705074186093
```

That leaves the garbage on the end. That's not garbage. Thats' your actual output. Everything up to

```
845630179
032918654
190745328
683074912
457201836
219863540
361429705
074186093
920357461
```

is the result of the `cout << ch;`s inside the while loop that's doing the collection. The

```
845630179032918654190745328683074912457201836219863540361429705074186093
```

On the end is the `for` loops. Since the newline wasn't stored they're printed out as one big block of digits.

To fix that we'll remove the output from the `while` loop and restore the newline in the `for` loop.

```
int main()
{
//parsing the textfile.
    vector<vector<char>> grid;
    fstream fin;
    char ch;
    string name("data.txt"); //File Name.
// 2D Vector.
    vector<char> temp;
// Temporary vector to be pushed
// into vec, since its a vector of vectors.
    fin.open(name.c_str(), ios::in);
// Assume name as an arbitary file.
    while (fin.get(ch))
    {
        if (ch != '\n')
        {
            temp.push_back(ch);
        }
        else
        {
            grid.push_back(temp);
            temp.clear();
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].size(); j++)
        {
            cout << grid[i][j];
        }
        cout << '\n'; // 
    }
}
```

And if we do this with a `vector<string>`, about a quarter of the code goes away.

```
 int main()
{
//parsing the textfile.
    vector<string> grid;
    fstream fin;
// 2D Vector.
    vector<char> temp;
// Temporary vector to be pushed
// into vec, since its a vector of vectors.
    fin.open("data.txt", ios::in);
// Assume name as an arbitary file.
    string line;
    while (getline (fin, line))
    {
        grid.push_back(line);
        temp.clear();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].size(); j++)
        {
            cout << grid[i][j];
        }
        cout << '\n'; // getline ate the newline. Have to put it back
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! You've helped me in the past i recognize your name. Also, im taking input from the command line. So how would i use arg v and argc for string input? (im new to c++ as a whole)

Comment: Your original code had the the input just about right. All you need to add is a `if (argc > 1)` test to make sure `argv[1]` actually exists. I left it out because it wasn't necessary to what I was trying to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works well for me.

If there is an enter at the end of your text file it will also push the last number to your grid. Otherwise you need to push the content of `temp` to `grid` after the while loop.

Comment: How does this explain dublicate line 8?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It's not my code. The code only prints one char whether or not the reading succeeds. Why should it print the whole line again?

Comment: ive put an enter but now it puts a 9 at the end of the last row making it 10 elements instead of 9